# PDF marked text for parser

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, apache-tika

I will have a lot PDF documents with same structure, how I can mark (or add some info to) a text. And then when I will parse PDF document I will known where I can find specified value by  marked id.

How I can get marked property by Apache-Tika or PDFBox?

For example: Create pdf file with text field marked as full name, then I parse it and try to find a value marked as full name.

Comment: Why would you want to mark and then extract from the same file? Maybe you mean there's one PDF as a template and many more with exactly the same geometry (filled blanks, etc.), and then your question is about extracting with respect to position on the page, no?

Comment: Adding on to what VadimR said, you should be "marking" the fields AFTER they're extracted. You could run tika on a template and see how the template is extracted and you could have you code respond accordingly for the rest of the "extractions" given by tika

Comment: VadimR, a PDF file created in one system and then this file uploads to another system that should parse this file and get some properties. PDF's not template, they just have same structure.

Comment: If you control PDF creation, then parts of PDF page content stream can be *marked content* (see PDF reference), but I don't know how to add or extract them with tools you mention, sorry. Or maybe your documents can be constructed as *PDF Forms*, with field titles as marks you talking about. Plus, you always can embed (*PDF-attachments*, *XMP* data, etc.) any information to be extracted later regardless of actual page content.